# st-table convert string to date

Tags: angularjs, smart-table

I have json object array binded to a table. Objects have a date column which is in date format but string. I need to change date format.

I tried;

```
<tbody>
<tr ng-repeat="row in table_data">
  <td>{{row.availabledate | date:'MMMM dd, yyyy'}}</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
```

But, since it is string it is not formatted. I dont want to convert it in a loop for the sake of performance. Is there a way to convert this string to date and then format it on html part?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is to make your own filter, then use the date filter.

This crude/raw filter expects a YYYYMMDD string and creates a date object from it that you can then use angular's date filter on.

```
app.filter('strToDate', function() {

  return function(input) {
    var year        = input.substring(0,4);
    var month       = input.substring(4,6);
    var day         = input.substring(6,8);
    // Do filter work here

    return new Date(year,month,day);

  }

});
```

and then

```
<td>{{row.availabledate | strToDate | date:'MMMM dd, yyyy'}}</td>
```

Here's a Plunker link with working example: https://plnkr.co/edit/hn5StpktiMLq2gWHAszu?p=preview

You could also just make your filter return the formatted date.

Comment: Glad to help, could you please mark the answer as an accepted answer if it was satisfactory :)

Answer (score 0):

Another way, doing all the work inside the filter:

```
app.filter('strToDate', function($filter) {
 //1. date value
 //2. the format input by user
 return function(input, format) {
  //Create the date object
  var year        = input.substring(0,4);
  var month       = input.substring(4,6);
  var day         = input.substring(6,8);
  var newDate = new Date(year,month,day);
  // return the format selected
  return $filter('date')(newDate , format)
  }
});
```

You can use the filter like this:

```
<td>{{row.availabledate | strToDate :'MMMM dd, yyyy'}}</td>
```